# How can I find out at a job interview whether the company is vegan friendly?

Tags: veganism, outreach, living-with-omnivores

I'm currently changing careers and moving into a new field. At my old job, I was really lucky to have a vegan boss and mostly vegetarian coworkers. Having lunch together was always great.

Now, given that I don't particularly enjoy having lunch where other people eat meat, I want to find out what attitude the people at my potential new workplace have during the interview, or before I have to make the final decision on an offer. My vague feeling is that I don't want to bring this topic up prominently during the interview, since I don't want to be labelled as "the vegan".

Comment: I'm wondering whether you might get better answers on Workplace. (Yes, this is definitely a vegan-specific issue, but how to bring up the topic gracefully may be more up their alley.)

Comment: @Erica, yes, I thought about that... I thought that people on Workplace wouldn't really appreciate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One *risky* but helpful move: Advertise yourself as being interested in veganism and/or vegan cooking (the latter will come across far less political) in whatever real-name social media profiles an employer is likely to read anyway before deciding whether to offer an interview. It is likely that they won't waste their and your time offering one if their company culture is truly intolerant about it.

Answer (score 2):

## Ask

I doubt that you would be forced to eat lunch in the company. If the company offers lunch as a perk; I see no reason why you wouldn't politely ask about the menu.

Being labeled is always a risk, but if that closes you doors, it's likely the doors you would not want to go through anyway.